# OCaml intesection function logical error

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

So I am trying to write a function that returns the list of elements l1 and l2 have in common, but it returns empty every time and I am unable to find the logical error to it. `

```
let rec intersection (l1 : 'a list) (l2 : 'a list) : 'a list = 
  let rec aux l1 l2 acc = match l1 with 
    | [] -> []
    | h1::t1 -> begin match l2 with
      | [] -> []
      | h2::t2 -> if h1 = h2 then aux t1 t2 (h1::acc) else aux l1 t2 acc 
      end in
    aux l1 l2 []
```

Answer (score 0):

In your aux function, you may want to return acc when l1 or l2 is empty, not returning [ ]. This is why the function returns [ ] every time. But as Jeffrey's answer stated, this still doesn't work correctly in case the order of elements in your two lists differ. You can maybe sort them beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

All of the recursive calls to `aux` pass `t2`, the tail of the second list. When it reaches the end of the second list, it finishes--there is no recursive call in this case. So, `aux` can only go through its second list one time. But (assuming there are no limitations on the orders of the lists) you need to go through the second list many times, once for each element of the first list.

For what it's worth, I would be tempted to use *two* helper functions for this problem.